# If $x_n = (\prod_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k})^\frac{2}{n(n+1)}$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = e$

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients, exponential-function

I try to prove the following:
$$x_n = \left(\prod_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\right)^\frac{2}{n(n+1)}$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = e$$
I want to use double sided theorem, so I've proven that
$$x_n \ge \frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$$
As it known, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} = e$. But I can't find such sequence $y_n$ that $x_n \le y_n$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} y_n = e$.

There is proof for lower bound:

$$x_n = \frac{(n!)^\frac{2}{n}}{(0!\cdot 1! \dots n!)^\frac{4}{n(n+1)}} \ge \frac{(n!)^\frac{2}{n}\cdot n}{(0!\cdot 1! \dots n!)^\frac{4}{n(n+1)}\cdot(n^n(n-1)^{n-1}(n-2)^{n-2}\dots2^2)^\frac{4}{n(n+1)}} = $$
$$= \frac{(n!)^\frac 2n \cdot n}{(n!)^\frac 4n} = \frac{n}{(n!)^\frac 2n} \ge \frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}$$

Comment: Could you give a sketch of the proof for $x_n\geq \frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} $, as it could perhaps be modified to give $x_n\leq c(n) \frac{n}{\sqrt[n]{n!}} $, where $c(n)\rightarrow 1$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a completely different approach.

We will use
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\tag{1}
$$
when the limit on the right exists.

Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}
&=\prod_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{n+1}{n-k+1}\\
&=\prod_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{n+1}{k}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^{\frac2{n(n+1)}}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\prod_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^{\frac2n}\right)^{\frac1{n+1}}\tag{3}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}\left.\binom{n+1}{k}^{\frac2{n+1}}\middle/\prod_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}^{\frac2n}\right.\tag{4}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}\left.\binom{n+1}{k}\middle/\prod_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\right.\right)^{\frac2{n+1}}\prod_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^{\frac{-2}{n(n+1)}}\tag{5}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}\left.\binom{n+1}{k}\middle/\prod_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\right.\right)^{\frac1{n+1}}\tag{6}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{n+1}{k}\right)^{\frac1{n+1}}\tag{7}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left.\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{n+1}{k}\middle/\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{k}\right.\tag{8}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\tag{9}\\[12pt]
&=e\tag{10}
\end{align}
$$
$(4)$: apply $(1)$
$(5)$: redistribute $\prod_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}^{-\frac2n}$
$(6)$: multiply both sides by the left side and take the square root
$(7)$: apply $(2)$
$(8)$: apply $(1)$
$(9)$: algebra

Comment: Where did you get (1) from? Looks like you're equating the results of ratio test and root test for series?

Comment: Take logs and you have [Stolz-Cesaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

Answer (score 9):

Using Riemann Sums,
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(\prod_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^{\frac2{n(n+1)}}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac2{n(n+1)}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^k\log(n-j+1)-\sum_{j=1}^k\log(j)\right)\tag{1}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}2\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\sum_{j=1}^k\log\left(1-\frac{j}{n+1}\right)\frac1{n+1}-\sum_{j=1}^k\log\left(\frac{j}{n+1}\right)\frac1{n+1}\right)\frac1n\tag{2}\\
&=2\int_0^1\left(\int_0^x\log(1-t)\,\mathrm{d}t-\int_0^x\log(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\
&=2\int_0^1\Big(-(1-x)\log(1-x)-x\log(x)\Big)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{4}\\
&=-4\int_0^1x\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{5}\\[6pt]
&=1\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
$(1)$: $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots1}$
$(2)$: distribute the $\frac1n$ and $\frac1{n+1}$; subtract $\frac{k}{n+1}\log(n+1)$ from each of the inner sums
$(3)$: $(2)$ is $\frac{n+1}{n}$ times the Riemann sum, on a $\frac1{n+1}\times\frac1{n+1}$ grid, for this double integral
$(4)$: apply $\int\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=x\log(x)-x+C$ twice
$(5)$: separate integral; change variables $x\mapsto1-x$; combine integrals

Therefore,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^{\frac2{n(n+1)}}=e\tag{7}
$$

Comment: To which function(s) do you apply the fact that the Riemann sums of a suitable function converge to its integral, at the step of your post where limits of sums are replaced by integrals?

Comment: @Did: Using $t=\frac{j}{n+1}$,
$\sum\limits_{j=1}^k\log\left(1-\frac{j}{n+1}\right)\frac1{n+1}$ is a Riemann sum for $\int_0^{k/(n+1)}\log(1-t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ and $\sum\limits_{j=1}^k\log\left(\frac{j}{n+1}\right)\frac1{n+1}$ is a Riemann sum for $\int_0^{k/(n+1)}\log(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$. Then, using $x=\frac{k}{n+1}$, $\sum\limits_{k=0}^nf\left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)\frac1{n+1}$ is the Riemann sum for the outer integral. I used $\frac1n$ to match the given form, assuming $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=1$.

Comment: Except that the theorem does not apply simultaneously to $n$ sums, each defined on its own interval, itself moving with $n$ (or one should show it does). // A rigorous approach would be to rewrite the first sum, say, as $(2/n(n+1))\sum\limits_{j=1}^n(n+1-j)\log(1-j/(n+1))=(2/n)\sum\limits_{j=1}^nA(j/(n+1))$ with $A:x\mapsto(1-x)\log(1-x)$. Likewise for the second sum.

Comment: @Did: This is just a Riemann sum for a double integral on a $\frac1{n+1}\times\frac1{n+1}$ grid.

Comment: You might want to include this in the answer.

Comment: @Did: Done. $\ %always wanted to say that$

Comment: @robjohn How Did you Obtain equation $(1)$? Can you please break it down. I am struggling for 5 hours. I am solving same question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607848/if-a-lim-n-to-infty-bigg-prod-k-0n-n-choose-k-bigg-dfrac1nn?noredirect=1#comment9709982_4607848

Comment: @mathophile: if you take the log of the equation in the Explanation of $(1)$, and remember that the log of a product is the sum of the logs, you get $(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

*Too late, more than likely too advanced but done for the fun of deriving asymptotics.*
$$\prod_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}=\frac{\big[\Gamma (n+1)\big]^n}{G(n+1)\, G(n+2)}$$ where $G(.)$ is  the [Barnes G-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function).

Using Stirling-like approximations
$$\log(G(p))=\frac{1}{4} p^2 (2 \log (p)-3)+\frac{1}{2} p (-2 \log (p)+2+\log (\pi )+\log (2))+$$ $$\frac{1}{12} \left(-6 \log \left(2 \pi  A^2\right)+5 \log
   (p)+1\right)-\frac{1}{12 p}-\frac{1}{240 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$
$$\log\Bigg[\prod_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \Bigg]=\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2} n (-\log (n)+2-\log (\pi )-\log
   (2))+\frac{1}{12} (24 \log (A)-4 \log (n)-1-6 \log (2 \pi
   ))-\frac{1}{12 n}+\frac{1}{180 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\log(x_n)=1-\frac 1 n \log \left(\frac{2 \pi  n}{e}\right)+\frac{24 \log (A)+2 \log (n)-7}{6 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

$$\color{blue}{x_n=e\left(1-\frac 1 n \log \left(\frac{2 \pi  n}{e}\right) \right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}$$

The relative error is less than $0.1$% as soon as $n>135$.