# If $A=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\prod_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}\bigg) ^{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}$. Then Find $A$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, binomial-theorem

> > If $$A=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\prod_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}\bigg) ^{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}$$. Then Find $A$

**My Approach:**

$\prod_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}=\prod_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\dfrac{(n!)^{n+1}}{\bigg(0!\cdot1!\cdot2!.....(n)!\bigg)^2}$.

Now I don't Know how to proceed further. This question was given to a High School Students in some paper.

Comment: you need to take $\ln$ and use Stirling's approximation. Or maybe this turns into an Riemann approximation.

Comment: @dezdichado I don't Know anything about Riemann Integral.

Comment: Everything you need should be in [If $x_n = (\prod_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k})^\frac{2}{n(n+1)}$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = e$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557338/if-x-n-prod-k-0n-binomnk-frac2nn1-then-lim-n-to-inft)