# $\lim_{n\rightarrow\ \infty\ } \sqrt[n]{G_n}$

Tags: limits

We are given that $$G_n=\sqrt[n+1]{\prod_{\ k=1}^nC_k^n}$$
We need to find
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\ \infty\ } \sqrt[n]{G_n}$$
I have a strong feeling that it can be done using Stolz-Cesaro Theorem, but just cannot execute it so any help would be great.

Comment: What do we know about the sequence $\{C_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$?

Comment: Anyways consider $\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\sqrt[n]{G_n}$

Comment: @Lorago $C_k^n$ is nothing but $\binom{n}{k}$

Comment: Stolz-Cesaro should indeed work.

Comment: @mathsisfun ah alright, I'm not used to that notation

Comment: Ah ok riemann sums got me done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Using algebra,
$$A_n=\prod_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}=\frac{\Gamma (n+1)^n}{G(n+1)\, G(n+2)}$$ where appears the BarnesG-function.

Have a look at my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557338/if-x-n-prod-k-0n-binomnk-frac2nn1-then-lim-n-to-inft/4608155#4608155) to continue to obtain more than the limit.